# Preflight validate() is invalid but in Console valid

Tags: java, encoding, base64

Currently I'm decoding a Base64 with Console:

```
base64 -di "myfile.txt" > mypdf.pdf
```

Which returns a **valid** pdf file.

But when I try this

```
DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pdf.getEncodedContent())));
        PreflightParser parser = new PreflightParser(dataSource);
        parser.parse();


        try (PreflightDocument document = parser.getPreflightDocument()) {
            document.validate();

            return !document.isEncrypted();
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex) {
            return false;
        }
```

I always get a validationException (pdf is not valid).

I think I need to change the configuration. I've already tried the following but that doesn't seem to help:

```
PreflightConfiguration config = document.getContext().getConfig();
config.setLazyValidation(true);
```

Stacktrace:

test.pdf is not valid: Unable to parse font metadata due to : Excepted xpacket 'end' attribute (must be present and placed in first)

Comment: removed [tag:apache] tag, make sure to pick a relevant new one if you want to be more specific than just "java" (make sure to read the tag's descriptions to pick the right one)

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: print out the stacktrace to see what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this ticket. For those who are interested:

The validation worked perfectly and the pdf files where not correct even if the reader /browser could open it (the pdf reader/browser did not show any warnings or error messages).

Try to convert your pdfs to **binary text** and check at least if your first two lines and the last line are 'pdf default' like:

```
%PDF-1.7
%µµµµ
...
%%EOF
```

if not, then the pdf has been generated wrong and the validation will fail.